# React and Material-UI - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'line_items') - How to fix?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'line_items')

I have a problem in this code could someone help me to solve it this is my code

```
``import React from 'react';
import { Typography, List, ListItem, ListItemText } from '@material-ui/core';

const Review = ({ checkoutToken }) => (
  <>
    <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>Order summary</Typography>
    <List disablePadding>
      {checkoutToken.live.line_items.map((product) => (
        <ListItem style={{ padding: '10px 0' }} key={product.name}>
          <ListItemText primary={product.name} secondary={`Quantity: ${product.quantity}`} />
          <Typography variant="body2">{product.line_total.formatted_with_symbol}</Typography>
        </ListItem>
      ))}
      <ListItem style={{ padding: '10px 0' }}>
        <ListItemText primary="Total" />
        <Typography variant="subtitle1" style={{ fontWeight: 700 }}>
          {checkoutToken.live.subtotal.formatted_with_symbol}
        </Typography>
      </ListItem>
    </List>
  </>
);`

export default Review;`
```

I hope this solve as soon as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you logged `checkoutToken.live` to check if `line_items` exists in your object?

As the [Stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-line_items) mention : This field is not included by default. To include it in the response, [expand](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects) the line_items field.

NodeJS Example

```
//retrieving a single Checkout Session

const checkout = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(
      'cs_test_...', {
      expand: ['line_items']
    }
);

//retrieving a list of Checkout Sessions

const checkoutSessions = await stripe.checkout.sessions.list({
  customer : 'cus_...',
  expand: ['data.line_items']
});
```